# AVCaptureSession specify resolution and quality of captured images obj-c iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avcapturesession, avcapture

Hi I want to setup `AV` capture session to capture images with specific resolution (and, if possible, with specific quality) using  iphone camera. here's setupping `AV` session code

```
// Create and configure a capture session and start it running
- (void)setupCaptureSession 
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    // Create the session
    self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // Configure the session to produce lower resolution video frames, if your 
    // processing algorithm can cope. We'll specify medium quality for the
    // chosen device.
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    // Find a suitable AVCaptureDevice
    NSArray *cameras=[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *device;
    if ([UserDefaults camera]==UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront)
    {
        device =[cameras objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    else
    {
        device = [cameras objectAtIndex:0];
    };

    // Create a device input with the device and add it to the session.
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input)
    {
        NSLog(@"PANIC: no media input");
    }
    [captureSession addInput:input];

    // Create a VideoDataOutput and add it to the session
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [captureSession addOutput:output];
    NSLog(@"connections: %@", output.connections);

    // Configure your output.
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
    dispatch_release(queue);

    // Specify the pixel format
    output.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];


    // If you wish to cap the frame rate to a known value, such as 15 fps, set 
    // minFrameDuration.


    // Assign session to an ivar.
    [self setSession:captureSession];
    [self.captureSession startRunning];
}
```

and `setSession`:

```
-(void)setSession:(AVCaptureSession *)session
{
    NSLog(@"setting session...");
    self.captureSession=session;
    NSLog(@"setting camera view");
    self.previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
    //UIView *aView = self.view;
    CGRect videoRect = CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 280.0, 255.0);
    previewLayer.frame = videoRect; // Assume you want the preview layer to fill the view.
    [previewLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
    //[aView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
}
```

and output methods:

```
// Delegate routine that is called when a sample buffer was written
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{ 
    //NSLog(@"captureOutput: didOutputSampleBufferFromConnection");

    // Create a UIImage from the sample buffer data
    self.currentImage = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

    //< Add your code here that uses the image >
}

// Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer 
{
    //NSLog(@"imageFromSampleBuffer: called");
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0); 

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); 
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);


    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context); 
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}
```

Everything is quite standard. But where and what should I change to specify the resolution of captured image and it's quality. Help me please

Comment: [Checkout a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758407/ios-capture-high-resolution-photo-while-using-a-low-avcapturesessionpreset-for-v/40609268#40609268). This might help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Refer to [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2) Capturing Still Images section regarding which sizes you'll get if you set one or another preset.

The parameter you should change is `captureSession.sessionPreset`, which has a type of `AVCaptureSession.Preset`.

Comment: I have a `UISlider` in my application using it user will specify higher or lower value he wants. But which values are higher?

Comment: `NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset320x240;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset960x540;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to go with something like this where cx and cy are your custom resolutions:

```
NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill,AVVideoScalingModeKey,
                           AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:cx], AVVideoWidthKey,
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:cx], AVVideoHeightKey,
                           nil];
_videoInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];
```