# Recording only audio and a single snap during recording through AVCamCaptureManager in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to record audio for 10 seconds and take a snap when I stop recording the audio using AVCamCaptureManager in Objective C.

I gone through

[AVCaptureSession specify resolution and quality of captured images obj-c iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312832/avcapturesession-specify-resolution-and-quality-of-captured-images-obj-c-iphone)

and implemented the same.
I am also using AVAudioSession to record audio when I start AVCamCaptureManager to take snap but it do not record audio its because AVCamCaptureManager also use the same audio device resource to record audio.

How can I do this? Please help..